# Best way to make $date and $hour into a PHP date?

Tags: php, date, datetime

A simple question, but a little bit hard to search for...

What is the easiest and simplest way to get a PHP date, when I have $date (formated as HTML5 input type=date), and $hour (00 to 23).

I want the result to be $date = "2014-01-24 05:00" (MySQL)

Comment: What is the input `$date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about `$formattedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime($date.' '.$hour.':00'))`

Answer (score 1):

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i");

Then you can use $date where ever the date is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going into a mysql Db you can do it right in the query

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE (`DATECOLUMN`) VALUES (
      DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '$hour' HOUR))"
```

Obviously don't forget to sanitize the inputs